# Decision tree unclassified data

Tags: self-study, cart

not sure if this is the place for this, please let me know if not! I'm trying to complete a piece of homework and one of the questions is :

Given this tree derived using the ID3 algorithm:

```
Gender = Male
    TV  = Yes
        Income = 40 - 50
            Age = 30 – 40 -> Take up = Yes
            Age = 40 – 50 -> Take up = No
        Income = 30 – 40 -> Take up = Yes
        Income = 50 - 60 -> Take up = Yes
        Income = 20 – 30 -> Take up = Yes
    TV = No -> Take up = no
```

and this unseen data case :

```
Gender -> Male
TV Promotion -> Yes
DVD Promotion -> No
Income -> 40 – 50
Age - > 20 – 30 
Take up -> ?
```

What should be the take up value of this case.

I have a feeling it's yes because it falls under the 30 - 40 age bracket but I'm trying to find out if there's actually a factual way of working it out but I'm not sure what I'm searching for. I seem to have searched the first 10 odd google pages of "unseen data on ID3 decision tree" but I'm not getting anything remotely useful. Relevant links would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This seems like the right place, but, since this is homework, you should add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the list. Since this is a self-study question, I won't give a full answer, but some hints.

If you have given the complete tree, then think about why there is no branch for people who are 20-30 like your new person. Then think about what would be most reasonable to do with your person.

One final hint: I do not think there is a definitively right answer to this question.

Comment: This tree was derived by the ID3 algorithm from a bigger dataset I have also, so I guess that's why it's split by income not age.  There are 20-30 age groups but as they don't fall into 40 - 50 income they're not listed on the tree, which obviously causes problems when new data is added.

Comment: Your tree is split by income and age, but in a specific order. Data that is out of range of earlier data is problematic for any method.

Comment: So there's no actual way of proving the answer. It's just decide the most reasonable decision. I was looking into pruning but I think I'm way off on that idea.

Comment: Pruning is certainly one reasonable choice.

Comment: I did try looking into post-pruning but didn't get anywhere in that respect. I couldn't find any examples that even remotely related to my problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in ID3, which I have never used.

Comment: I think I've found that post pruning will give me the answer I want. Now just need to try and understand this rule pruning !